# count pixels of a given colour in the bitmap represented by a quadtree

Tags: java, quadtree

I can't seem to figure out how to count pixels with different colours.

should I use bfs method first or anything else?

```
public int countPixels(Colour colour) {
    int count = 0;
    //Colour c1 = Colour.WHITE.getTexture();
    //Colour c2 = Colour.BLACK.getTexture();
    return count;
}
```